# jQuery Masonry/Isotope fluid layout with proper gutters and no wrapping

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, fluid

I've been working on getting a proper fluid layout working with Masonry/Isotope. I've run into a number of snags along the way, the last of which I've been unable to solve.

**My objectives were:**

1. Enable a fluid isotope image grid layout that resizes photos on the fly
2. Have the image grid horizontally centered in the window
3. Have a gutter that doesn't cause the right column to A) wrap, or B) show off-center

I began looking at this question: [jQuery Isotope: Fluid setup like Beyonce's website only works after resizing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693381/jquery-isotope-fluid-setup-like-beyonces-website-only-works-after-resizing-win), but while it works to solve that immediate problem, it doesn't handle gutters and multiple columns.

I managed to edit the selected answer's jsfiddle to clean it up and expand it:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwwMC/4/

*(Please forgive the lack of line breaks, but jsfiddle was creating `&nbsp;`'s between columns messing up the gutter).*

I've successfully managed to solve problem #1; problem #2 can be easily accomplished by creating a parent div with a set width and `margin: 0 auto;`; that leaves us with problem #3:

If you use css to add padding or a transparent border to each `<li>` elements (say, `margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;` or even the equivalent using `border`), we run into a problem. All of a sudden the right column wraps into the next line! This, of course, is expected behaviour, and one would expect to solve it simply by applying `display: inline-block;` to the `<li>` elements (which I've done) and `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent element (which I commented out).

Unfortunately if you enable the nowrap, it produces the problematic behaviour that the `<ul>` element doesn't abide by the parent `<div>`'s width, and all of the images appear in one single row.

**The ultimate question:** How can I get this to work properly so that I've got three columns working with a gutter in between but perfectly aligned to the right and left of the parent element? I've even tried floating the images, but then there is some strange behavior with isotope.

Comment: Also for the record, I've encountered this issue in several cases, but I'm aware that it's an open issue with Isotope:

https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! It appears that I should be able to do this via the following code sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/remus/4fYUb/

To enable the gutter, I simply added `outline: 10px solid white;` to the css.